# LM.Detection_x64.exe (XML Scan Engine) constantly using CPU

Tags: windows-7, task-manager

I always run task manager minimized to watch my CPU usage.  My CPU has been running at at least 12% for the past 2 days.  (8 cores)  The process taking the CPU is:

**LM.Detection_x64.exe (XML Scan Engine)**

I did a google search to find what it is.  I don't have any Lumension or Novell products installed on my laptop to my knowledge.  (I went to Programs and did a search for those keywords).

I tried closing all of my programs and the process still exists.  I even rebooted today.

What is causing this program to constantly use one core?

Comment: Could you use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to find out more details about the executable file and add them to your question? Specifically, the MD5 hash of the executable, the command line arguments (if any), the location of the directory from where it's running and the parent process (if any). Something [like this](http://i.imgur.com/IXMkl0X.png) would also do.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I have installed Process Explorer and used it to "replace" task manager.  The problem mysteriously went away.  What should I do with this question, delete it?

Comment: I guess so. Why try solving a problem where there isn't any? However, you might want to wait for a while to see if the problem recurs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as per OP comment "The problem mysteriously went away. " so question is not useful for future visitors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LM_DETECTION is the scanning engine for KACE tools.  It is part of the system your system administration folks are likely using to do your updates and patches.

Comment: LM.Detection is also used as part of the VIPRE anti-virus software.

Answer (score 0):

This is a security scanning tool made by Lumension, and most likely deployed by your system administrator - try asking them about it. If this is a personal / home computer, it may have been installed by the vendor, so try asking their support about it.

https://www.lumension.com/Resources/Premium-Security-Tools.aspx

It can be found in in C:\Program Files\Lumension\LEMSSAgent

Comment: Thank you.  I checked Program Files and Program Files x86, but did not find it.  I have since upgraded my OS with a clean image.